# Trouble understanding actionbarsherlock Tabs / Fragments / Activitys

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, actionbarsherlock

I believe I have a very straightforward use case but having problems getting my head around the fundamentals it seems.  I'm new to Fragments and only feel I have to delve into them since Tabs are unfortunately deprecated.

All I'm wanting to achieve is a tabbed layout where in the past I'd have an activity per tab.

I'm going through the samples that come with ActionBarSherlock, and have some confusion, I wish they completed the Tab Navigations so they actually link to activities and not just set text in the content pane.. I think that would make things much easier to understand for many people..

I started my 'Main' activity extended SherlockFragmentActivity and implementing the TabListener.. to find that this is pretty pointless as they suggest I use Fragments, so referring to the Fragment samples I then looked at the FragmentTabs sample which doesn't implement the TabListener but instead has its own inner class for managing the tabs.

Unfortunately, the tabs in demo samples look far better than the ones in the FragmentTabs sample.. the fragment Tabs sample look like the Tabs we've been used to seeing in Android (very poor) compared to the more modern looking ActionBar tabs in the 'demo' sample.

So what I'm trying to accomplish is mix both examples so I have the nice modern looking action bar tabs but also understand how to load a new activity when clicked on.

Any help here would be appreciated, I'm starting to really feel like banging my head against a wall.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm new to Fragments and only feel I have to delve into them since Tabs are unfortunately deprecated.

Tabs are not deprecated. The use of activities in tabs has been deprecated, in the form of deprecating `ActivityGroup` (i.e., putting activities inside of activities). You are certainly welcome to use `TabHost` without putting activities in tabs.

> I wish they completed the Tab Navigations so they actually link to activities

That is because putting activities inside of activities is deprecated.

> So what I'm trying to accomplish is mix both examples so I have the nice modern looking action bar tabs but also understand how to load a new activity when clicked on.

Don't put activities in tabs. Either [use fragments for the contents of tabs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs) or [otherwise modify your UI when tabs are clicked upon](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionBar/TabFragmentDemo).